# why parsley don't validate each field (on losing focus for example) while I call $('#myForm').validate();?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

Why parsley don't validate each field (on losing focus for example) while I call $('#myForm').validate();?

Validation of field on losing focus starts to work only after I validate the whole form.

In javascript I set parsley to my form in that way:

```
formObject.parsley({trigger: 'change'});
```

No attributes are set to my form in html.
No attributes except validation rule attributes are set to form fields.
Setting data-parsley-trigger="change" to form fields don't help.

Answer (score 0):

Parsley uses a threshold before which validation is triggered and by default its 3 characters.

See official documentation - http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Validation threshold #2.0
data-parsley-validation-threshold="10"
Used with trigger option above, for all key- events, do not validate until field have a certain number of characters. Default is 3

So can you please try entering 3+ characters and change focus to check if its performing the validation correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But no, it doesn't help(

Answer (score 0):

Late response...

```
data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
```

Additionally, the Trigger event supports these [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Official [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-field)